# Detecting a line in an image and save its coordinates

Tags: r, image

I have an image representing an intensity graph:

[intensity graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7atd.png)

In order to multiplicate two intensitiy graphs I need to save the coordinates of this graph. Thus, I first want to find the (middle or one border of the) line and then get its coordinates. So far I tried a few things. Which came nearest to the solution was using the [LineSegmentDetector](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/image.LineSegmentDetector/image.LineSegmentDetector.pdf) package:

```
library(pixmap)
image <- read.pnm(file = "graph.pgm", cellres = 1)
x <- image@grey * 255
linesegments <- image_line_segment_detector(x)
linesegments
plot(image)
plot(linesegments, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

This gives me a couple of line segments:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bho4L.png)

However, the aim is to get one line of 1 pixel width like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7uyq.png)

Subsequently, I would need the coordinates of this graph. I would need one y value for every pixel in x direction.
I hope my problem is clear and am thankful for any help!

Comment: It's of course nice to do these things programmatically, but if you only have a few of these plots and the data extraction only needs to be done once then https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/ is a good option.

Comment: This tool is genuinely amazing, thank you! I can't believe I didn't find it. I will use it for now, though it would still be nice to automate it as I have many graphs und the calibration of the axes is quite tedious to do every time. Especially as my graphs have all the same size and axes.

Comment: There is also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digitize/index.html perhaps you can save axis settings? (I only briefly used it but WebPlotDigitizer was a lot easier for my purpose)